# Pass/Firefox master key integration?

Tags: shell-script, password, firefox

I handle my passwords with [pass](http://www.passwordstore.org/), and I use the Firefox master password functionality. The master password is rather long and "safe" and stored in `pass` along with the others.

For now, my usual Firefox startup looks like:

- start Firefox
- get prompted for master password
- fire up CLI
- `$pass firefox`
- Enter GPG key password
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> master password
- use Firefox

How can I make this procedure easier and quicker? Ideally, I'd just want to be prompted once for the GPG key password as soon as I start Firefox and then get back to what I'm doing.

Comment: You could use [`passmenu`](http://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/contrib/dmenu/passmenu) to speed it up (marginally)...

Comment: I'm sorry it is not immediately clear. What does it do? :)

Comment: It retrieves the password from [dmenu](http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/) and copies it to your clipboard; no need to open a terminal...

Comment: maybe use `gpg-agent` ??